# C# ToString("#.00") removes my first value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I pass 0,00 to `ToString("#.00")` and it gives me `.00` instead while i need it to be `0.00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's working as intended. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), the `#` format specifier means:

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.
>
> Note that no digit appears in the result string if the corresponding digit in the input string is a non-significant 0. For example, 0003 ("####") -> 3.

If you want a result of `0.00`, use a format string of `"0.00"`.

The `0` format specifier is documented (in the summary table):

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

There are more details in the specific sections for [the "#" custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier) and [the "0" custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier).